# Dark mode flickers a white background for a millisecond on reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add this dark mode feature in my app. It uses localstorage to store the user's preference for future usage. So the problem now is when the dark mode is enabled, and the page is reloaded for some reason, eg. if the user deliberately reloads the page, or submits a form, then there's a flicker of white background all over the page before it turns to be dark. It stays a fraction of a second. It just doesn't look professional.

Haven't found any solution yet. So please help me out.

PS. The snippet below won't work here in SO as the code includes `localStorage` object.

Here's the code:

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('#dark-mode-button input[type="checkbox"]');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
            toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
}

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    }else {        
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }    
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #495057;
  --bg-color-primary: #F5F5F5;
}

body{
  background-color: var(--bg-color-primary); 
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --primary-color: #8899A6;
  --bg-color-primary: #15202B;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dark-mode-button">
    <input id="chck" type="checkbox">Dark Mode
    <label for="chck" class="check-trail">
      <span class="check-handler"></span>
    </label>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>                     
</table>
```

Comment: Its most likely because the JS hasnt loaded and executed the check yet. So the page loads in normal mode, JS initialises, sets the dark mode and then it changes.

Comment: What @EmreKoc says is correct. I would recommend putting the theme detection script as one of the first things on your page. Other than that, don't reload the whole page on navigation - just replace the part that's changed with ajax requests.

Comment: Guys, sorry but can you please tell me which part of the code I should separate and where should I put that ?

Comment: I dont think I'll be able to stop the user from reloading the page. Cause my app needs a lot of reload as the values updates dynamically every second. Please note that, when I say app, it is the actual one I'm working on. The code here is just the issue I'm facing right now!

Comment: Move the part of the code that sets the dark-light mode in a render-blocking fashion - meaning, inside the `<head>` of your document. Place the remaining scripts as usual, right before the closing `</body>` tag.  That way, the browser will stop to interpret your JS inside head and will assign the needed `data-theme` attribute to your `<html>` tag.

Comment: @roko, do you mean this part? const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
            toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
}

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan is correct. But, consider your `querySelector` you may need event delegation if you are to prioritize the loading of this script

Comment: Can you guys please speak in English? :( Someone help me in placing the code in the correct place. Not an expert here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It would be ideal to **block the page rendering** by placing a small `<script>` tag inside the `<head>` of your Document. By doing so the DOM parser should stop and call the JavaScript interpreter, assign the `data-theme` attribute to `<html>` and than continue where left. Give it a try:

Place this `<script>` inside `<head>` - even before the `<link>` or `<style>` tags:

```html
<head>
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: set this in <HEAD> top before any other tag.
    const setTheme = (theme) => {
      theme ??= localStorage.theme || "light";
      document.documentElement.dataset.theme = theme;
      localStorage.theme = theme;
    };
    setTheme();
  </script>

  <!-- meta, title, etc... -->
  <!-- link, style, etc... -->
</head>
```

Then, right **before the closing `</body>` tag** use all the other scripts in a non-render-blocking manner:

```html
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
<!-- other <script> tags here -->
<!-- Closing </body> </html> goes here -->
```

and inside your i.e: `js/index.js` file use:

```js
const elToggleTheme = document.querySelector('#dark-mode-button input[type="checkbox"]');

elToggleTheme.checked = localStorage.theme === "dark";

elToggleTheme.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const theme = elToggleTheme.checked ? "dark" : "light";
  setTheme(theme);
});
```

PS: You can also place the above JavaScript code into your *.js* file if you want to keep all your scripts in one place.

If you need a creative idea for a Dark theme mode toggle checkbox see this answer: [Toggle theme button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948817/383904)

Comment: In my case, I was setting the theme switcher class inside `document.body`. Taking advantage from the knowledge given by this solution, I added a single script on `<head>` that I divided in two parts: one part that handled the blocker bit (isolated, as in the solution), and another part that packed the rest of the functionality inside a function and assigned it to `window.onload`.