# Using Local Storage to remember last clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use local storage to keep the last clicked button even if the page is reloaded. I tried the following code but it didn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/2L0d64hv/1/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button").on("click", function() {
        $("#collapse").slideToggle("slow");
        if ($(this).val() == "Hide") {
          $(this).val("Show");
          $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d35f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
        } else {
          $(this).val("Hide");
          $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
        }
  localStorage.imageStatus = $('#button').data('status');
  
  });
  
  const initialStatus = localStorage.imageStatus || 'Hide';
$('#button').data('status', initialStatus);
  
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" value="Hide" id="button" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></button>
<div id="collapse">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: Please describe what "didn't work" means exactly.

Comment: You should decide, either use `"Hide"` or `"hide"`... typos are not allowed! :)

Comment: 'Hide' ! Thanks for pointing that out. And the code doesn't remember the last clicked button on page reload.

Comment: Maybe because you don't have any data in "status" on button

Comment: @Bob why not lowercase? It's simpler to write and remember

Comment: I will change it all to lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use variables. You already have your `localStorage.imageStatus`
Here's how to read on DOM ready and toggle it thanks to some handy reusable functions: http://jsfiddle.net/ch2mzftu/1/

```js
const $btn = $("#button");
const $col = $("#collapse");

if (!localStorage.imageState) localStorage.imageState = "hide";

const toggleState = () => {
  localStorage.imageState = localStorage.imageState === "hide" ? "show" : "hide";
};

const applyState = () => {
  const isHide = localStorage.imageState === "hide";
  $col[isHide ? "slideUp" : "slideDown"]();
  $btn.attr("src",
    isHide ?
    "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" :
    "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d35f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
  );
};

applyState();      // Apply state on DOM ready!

$btn.on("click", () => { 
  toggleState();   // Toggle LS value
  applyState();    // and apply new state!
});
```

```html
<input type="image" data-status="Hide" id="button" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
<div id="collapse">Hello</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Change website state depending on localStorage variable

Another better solution would be to **not use jQuery at all**,
rather - handle the desired elements states exclusively via CSS in relation to the `data-hide` attribute in `<html>` element:

- Use a render blocking `<script>` (in `<head>`) that will pause the DOM parser and set the initial data to the `html` element
- Toggle the `data-hide` attribute of the HTML element  using JS
- Read more: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>TEST</title>

        <script>
            // Render blocking on purpose! Keep this here in <head>
            if (!localStorage.imageState) localStorage.imageState = "show";
            document.documentElement.dataset.state = localStorage.imageState;
        </script>

        <style>
            #button {
                border: 0;
                background: transparent;
            }
            #button img {
                display: none;
                height: 60px;
            }
            #collapse {
                transition: 0.5s;
                transform: translateY(-100%);
                opacity: 0;
            }
            html[data-state="hide"] #button img:nth-child(1) {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            html[data-state="show"] #button img:nth-child(2) {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            html[data-state="show"] #collapse {
                transform: translateY(0%);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="button">
            <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWYU.jpg?s=328&g=1">
        </button>
        <div id="collapse">Hello from Roko</div>

        <script>
            const EL_button = document.querySelector("#button");
            EL_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
                localStorage.imageState = localStorage.imageState === "show" ? "hide" : "show";
                document.documentElement.dataset.state = localStorage.imageState;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, one question how can I automatically show content as default?

Comment: @Bob have you tried to use `"show"` in line 4?

Comment: Thanks again. I know I'm being a pain but every time I reload the page it shows content for 0.5/1 second then hides it - is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Bob only in a render blocking way. Or inverse your logic.

Comment: @Bob see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904

Comment: I tried using 
<script>
if (localStorage.imageState) document.documentElement.setAttribute("hide", localStorage.imageState);
 </script> but it didn't work

Comment: @Bob `hide` is not a valid HTML attribute. Study the provided answers and comments. I'm sure you'll make it! PS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: I tried changing them it to img, src, #button, data, data-status and none worked.

Comment: @Bob do you know what is `document.documentElement` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement If you're assigning an attribute to the `<html>` element than use CSS to handle some child appropriately. `html[data-hide] #button {styles here!!!}`

Comment: let's start again. I have taken your answer to my original question and pasted it with some edits into the footer script. It works! But to render like you said I am using your code in the header section. I have the following:  <script>
     if (localStorage.imageState) document.documentElement.setAttribute("NO IDEA", localStorage.imageState);
    </script>

I don't understand your point with CSS? I only have  #button {
 float: right;
}

Comment: CSS is the first to trigger. JS should wait for DOM ready to handle elements. That's the 1s you're waiting to see the changes. Instead, when using a render block method you can tap into `<html>` and set CSS accordingly. than let the other part of the JS wait for DOM ready - The user should see whatever CSS presented before JS catches up. For example, if you use in CSS `html[data-hide] #collapse {display: none;}` the user will not see that element hiding (animating to hide).

Comment: I still see the animation after using your code. I even inserted !important in css

Comment: OK, let me create a local environment with your code - seems like you're having a really hard time to incorporate. I'll be right back

Comment: @Bob meanwhile, when you inspect Elements in Dev Tools - do you see the `<html data-hide="` in the HTML tag?

Comment: @Bob what should be the default state? Hidden or visible?

Comment: Yes I actually inserted that attribute. Let me restart browser.

Comment: Ok, now I don't see anything.... It is visible as default

Comment: Ok, it works but now another problem - it animates when the button is showing content...

Comment: Added an example. @Bob

Comment: Doesn't work with my web page. Something must be interfering with it

Comment: I'm really sorry to hear. I've added an entire runnable code.

Comment: I did try your code separately and it did work. So, I will try to find my problem... Thanks for your help. I did like the Javascript approach but I am new to Javascript so I had no clue what to change etc . At least with CSS I have a chance

Comment: Okay I found the problem - it is div class="container" from bootstrap css but I need this code. Do you have alternative solution for rendering?

Comment: The css also affects my navbar dropdown so this css approach isn't good for me sorry..

Comment: please help me with the jquery approach

Comment: @Bob jQuery *is* JavaScript. What's wrong with the above approach? Please create a jsFiddle.net with the code you have so far.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap CSS. <div class="container"></div> surrounds the button HTML and interferes with the code somehow. Also, it stops my navbar dropdown from working...

Comment: I am using http://jsfiddle.net/ch2mzftu/1/ currently because the CSS approach doesn't work with my Bootstrap CSS

Comment: @Bob ...why do you use `input type="image"` ? Is that a form? Why don't you use a CSS with `background-image`? and than again a special class that defines the other backgrounc-image? Using JS you can toggle a class but CSS will be the one to dictate the imagae - not clunky unnecessary `<input>` and JS code.

Comment: I can do that but will it fix the render issue? The code you provided previously actually does the job but just the delay in hiding the content is annoying me

Comment: The problem with css is that it interferes with my other css - this is why I prefer Javascript

Comment: @Bob don't use `<input type="image"` for no obvious reason. Use CSS. Use JS to toggle a general class or `data` to HTML or a specific Element. Define inside your CSS the behavior of those elements.

Comment: If done properly, nothing has to interfere with anything.

Comment: I used your code to show you my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/1nbrzvw8/5/

The button only works when you click the top half? I am using different images so after the content is hidden, I can't show it again.

Comment: @Bob does this works better? http://jsfiddle.net/m89kh1dL/ ? Or this: http://jsfiddle.net/m89kh1dL/1/ - It was a smallCSS fix. the element had opacity 0 but it was still there overlaying the button preventing the button to receive the click.

Comment: Second one works but inteferes with navbar which I will show you soon. Quick question: anyway to hide the content on the spot without translating it upwards because it looks weird on my design

Comment: @Bob Yes, I'm trying right now to circumvent that jQuery's `.slideToggle` issue. Will show my results hopefully in a minute.

Comment: Thanks!!! That is much better - I just need the image to show fully but other than that it is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
<input type="button" id="btn-1" onclick="rememberButton(this.id)" value="Button"></input>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function rememberButton(btn) {
    localStorage.setItem("clickedButton", btn);
}
```

By this way the code stores the button id in the localstorage.
If you want to get the last clicked button id you can use `localStorage.getItem("clickedButton");`

Comment: Where precisely do I add the javascript code ?

Comment: You can simply put it inside of an html script tag `<script>`