# Efficient dark mode theming with toggle for mobile HTML

Tags: html, css, media-queries, darkmode

I have been looking around at ways to have a **mobile efficient** dark mode theme, that is both automatic and can be toggled. By mobile efficient I mean high-latency, low-bandwidth, low-CPU friendly:

- only the relevant stylesheet is loaded (when light is active, dark stylesheet is not loaded, and vice-versa) to save on bandwidth
- no full-screen flashing
- no cookies

Solutions I have found do not have these properties, they are either using a fat CSS with both themes combined, or they're using two stylesheets, which can results in full-screen flashes when the user chose a theme different from the system default (as they are controlled through JS executed *after* the stylesheets are referenced in the DOM).

My best alternative so far is "efficient", but relies on document.write in a small inline script in the document head, it goes like:

```
let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
if (!theme) {
   theme = (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches)?"dark":"light"
}
if (theme == "dark") {
   document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="dark.theme.css" />');
} else {
   document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="light.theme.css" />');
}
```

The localStorage entry is managed by regular JS when manually toggled by the user.

I have tried all ways to mutate the link DOM element, and they all fail, resulting either in flashing or delayed CSS loading (with non-presented HTML being transiently visible).

I wonder if there is an approach that would still be efficient, support toggle and not rely on document.write ?

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a class "is-dark" to the html tag? To keep your css as lean as possible, you could define all your colors as css custom properties and redefine them whithin the scope of "is-dark". So you only have to deliver these custom properties twice, which should be manageable.

You still need JS to add the class, but you would not need document.write. That would eliminate the flicker in two of three cases, namely when the dark theme is selected by media query and when selecting it with the switch.

So this would look something like this:

```
:root {
  --clr-primary:                      #8e211a;
  --clr-secondary:                    #5e737a;
…
}


.is-dark {
  --clr-primary:                      black;
  --clr-secondary:                    white;
}


.myElement {
  color: var(--clr-secondary);
  background-color: var(--clr-primary);
}
```

That leaves us with the problem of the third case: Flickering after reload when the dark theme was selected per switch before the reload. In this case the light theme will be used until the JS hits and switches it to the dark theme.

The best bet seems to be blocking the page rendering until JS is ready as shown in this thread: [Dark mode flickers a white background for a millisecond on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033412/dark-mode-flickers-a-white-background-for-a-millisecond-on-reload)

Comment: I tried it as well, it suffers from both a bulkier CSS and from the transient flashing (when the CSS is already in cache, the browser will occasionally apply it before the JS can add the class on the slower devices, or if something holds back the JS (like JS not in cache). Even when the JS is th first body element, the (still empty) page background can flash black/white...

Comment: Are you sure you did what I suggested? I edited my answer to show what I mean. If you use custom properties, you only have to re-declare them for ".is-dark", which is just a very small amount of repeating whithin your stylesheet (you only need one!) - and it will be (hopefully) gzipped anyway. So I can't imagine there will be any noteworthy bloating, and there will be no flickering content. The moment you add that class, the browser will render the colors instantly.

Comment: ".is-dark" is for the switch, of course. You can do the same with a media query: @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { … }

Comment: The theme I'm using is for a bootstrap layout, which means SASS, which means it's very verbose (eventually they'll ditch SASS and use CSS variables, but we're not there yet). However that still would not help for the time interval between when the stylesheet is loaded (which can be instant if in cache) and the time when the JS runs (which can be short, but is not zero). The document.write blocks the main thread, which is also what prevents the flicker.

Comment: SASS: There is no reason why one could not use custom properties in SASS. Just replace the color values ;)  Flicker: As far as I understand it, there are three possible scenarios: First: no dark theme at all - no flicker. Second: dark theme by media query - page will be rendered after evaluating the media queries - no flicker. Third: User chooses to switch to dark theme and uses the switch - which he only can do after page is rendered. The moment the class is added, the browser will render the new colors instantly - no flicker. Do I miss something?

Comment: The flicker comes when the user selection is different from the OS theme, ie. when user chose light on a dark os, or dark on light os. When the selection is performed, there is no issue, and it would be a one-time issue anyway. The actual issue occurs the next time he opens the website: media query will select dark as that's the OS setting, but then JS will run and apply stored setting override to light (or vice-versa). And there is a chance on each access or page navigation...

Comment: I see. So the problem is "store the users choice and apply it immediately" ... I'd say "block the rendering until the JS hits" is out of the question :D Hmmm, tricky one … I guess this is no SPA ...?

Comment: Well, "blocking the rendering" is exactly what is recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033412/dark-mode-flickers-a-white-background-for-a-millisecond-on-reload

Comment: Interesting trick of attaching the attribute to the html element rather than body, as html element already exists in head, while body does not, so this can happen before the stylesheet links are parsed, avoiding the flicker. I guess this also makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: can you update your reply with the details une the comments? I'll then accept it!