# Toggle dark mode - Problem with newly created elements

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to make JS **dark mode toggle** with **click** event but it works
with HTML elements but it doesn't work with created elements with JavaScript using DOM.

```js
let body = document.querySelector(`body`);
let input = document.querySelector(`.input`);
let addBtn = document.querySelector(`.add`);
let form = document.querySelector(`.form`);
let container = document.querySelector(`.tasks`);

form.addEventListener(`submit`, (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const task = input.value;
  if (!task) {
    window.alert(`please fill the input!`);
  } else {
    const taskEl = document.createElement(`div`);
    taskEl.classList.add(`task`);

    const taskContentEl = document.createElement(`div`);
    taskContentEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
    taskEl.appendChild(taskContentEl);
    container.appendChild(taskEl);

    input.value = ``;
  }
});

function darkMode() {
  let darkBtn = document.querySelector(`.btn`);

  darkBtn.onclick = () => {
    form.classList.toggle(`formDark`);
    input.classList.toggle(`inputDark`);
    body.classList.toggle(`bodyDark`);
    //here is the code that's not works 
    taskEl.classList.toggle(`inputDark`);
  };
}
darkMode();
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">Dark mode</button>
<form class="form">
<input>
</form>
<div class="tasks"></div>
```

Comment: Makes no sense to add a list of elements to toggle classes from-to. Simply: just toggle some *`"dark"`* className on `body` - the rest is done purely by CSS, remember? `.dark .someDeepChild {`

Comment: `let body` (etc) should be `const body`

Comment: Class selectors like `let form = document.querySelector(".form");` are error prone. Add one more `.form` or `.input` in the DOM and see your JS fail on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer: [**Dark Mode**: toggle using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904) on how to implement *Dark mode* toggle using LocalStorage as example.

---

Toggle dark mode styles on **present or future elements**?

Simple. Don't use a specific JS list of all your elements to toggle classes from.
**Just toggle a *`"dark"`* class on the `body` element.** Then, use **CSS** to style everything else:

```js
document.body.classList.toggle("dark");
```

```css
.dark .input {}
.dark .add {}
.dark .someFutureElement {}
```

---

Example with a remake of your code:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);


// App: Tasks

const elInput = el(`#taskInput`);
const elAdd = el(`#taskAdd`);
const elForm = el(`#taskForm`);
const elTasks = el(`#tasks`);

const createTask = (task) => {
  tasks.push(task);
  const elTask = elNew(`li`, {textContent: task, className: "task"});
  elTasks.append(elTask);
};

elForm.addEventListener(`submit`, (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const task = elInput.value.trim(); // Trim from whitespaces!
  if (!task) return alert(`Please, fill the input!`);
  createTask(task);
  elInput.value = ``;
});

// Init: Populate existing tasks
const tasks = ["Drink coffee", "Develop some app"];
tasks.forEach(createTask);


// App: Dark mode

const elBody = el(`body`);
const elToggleDark = el(`#toggleDark`);
elToggleDark.addEventListener("click", () => {
  elBody.classList.toggle("dark", elToggleDark.checked);
});
```

```css
.dark {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.dark #taskInput {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  color: #fff;
}

.dark ol {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" id="toggleDark"> Toggle Dark Mode</label>

<form id="taskForm">
  <input id="taskInput" type="text" placeholder="Task...">
  <button id="taskAdd">Add</button>
</form>

<ol id="tasks"></ol>
```

Comment: could you explain more an aplly your soultion on my code?

Comment: @mofarih added an example, basically exactly as I described it in the first couple of paragraphs. Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

On the first event listener you can check for dark mode already on the body tag

```
form.addEventListener(`submit`, (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  const task = input.value;

  const createTaskEl = () => {
    const taskEl = document.createElement(`div`);
    taskEl.classList.add(`task`);

    const taskContentEl = document.createElement(`div`);
    taskContentEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
    taskEl.appendChild(taskContentEl);
    container.appendChild(taskEl);

    input.value = ``;
  }  

  if (!task) {
    window.alert(`please fill the input!`);

  } else {

      // Check if the body element is already in in dark mode
      if(!body.classList.contains('bodyDark')){
        createTaskEl()
      } else {
        createTaskEl()
        let taskEl = document.querySelector(`.task`);
        taskEl.classList.add(`inputDark`);
      }
  }
});
```

You needed to check that taskEl exists first.

```
function darkMode() {

  let darkBtn = document.querySelector(`.btn`);

    darkBtn.onclick = () => {

        let taskEl = document.querySelector(`.task`);

        const primaryEls = () => {
            form.classList.toggle(`formDark`),        
            input.classList.toggle(`inputDark`),
            body.classList.toggle(`bodyDark`)
        }

        if(taskEl){
            primaryEls();
            taskEl.classList.toggle(`inputDark`); 
        } else {
            primaryEls();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: this looks works good but there is a proplem if i click on dark mode button before adding any tasks the dark mode on taskEl but if i click on dark mode button after adding  tasks the dark mode works relly fine, how do i reslove this proplem

Comment: and it's only apply it in first task

Comment: `container.classList.toggle(\`inputDark\`);` instead of taskEl