# Localstorage keeps returning false

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Whenever I set local storage item, it is being returned as false all the time whenever I try to get the item from first line. Why is this happening?
Whenever `darkMode` is true then the storage should return true, but it is returning false. When I refresh my page, then it should console log `add yes`

```js
const json = localStorage.getItem("dark_mode")
const currentMode = JSON.parse(json)

let darkMode = true;

if(currentMode) {
    darkMode = true

} else {
    darkMode = false
}

setDark(darkMode)

function setDark() {

if(darkMode) {
    console.log('add yes')
  } else {
    console.log('add no')
  }

  localStorage.setItem("dark_mode", JSON.stringify(darkMode))

}
```

Comment: your variable `darkMode` is pretty much useless and just adds unnecessary complexity, you could use only `currentMode`

Comment: I use `darkMode` to add dark class or remove it

Comment: Unnecessarily. You only need one variable not two.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add unnecessary complexity. Use only one meaningful variable: `isDarkMode` which intuitively by its *is-* prefix implies a Boolean type.

Also, when first time getting your localStorage value, make sure to use a **fallback** using the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) - to prevent the JSON.parse giving you a String value as `"undefined"` which by itself evaluates always to `true`.

```js
let isDarkMode = JSON.parse(localStorage.dark_mode ?? false);

const toggleDarkMode = () => {
  // Toggle boolean
  isDarkMode = !isDarkMode; 
  // Test
  console.log(`Mode is: ${isDarkMode ? "dark" : "light"}`);
  // Store new mode
  localStorage.dark_mode = JSON.stringify(isDarkMode);
  // Return the new mode
  return isDarkMode;
}

// Toggle whenever is needed
toggleDarkMode();

// If you want to know the new mode either just check using
// console.log(isDarkMode)
//
// or directly:
// const newMode = toggleDarkMode();
// console.log(newMode)
```

Some additional resources for handling Dark mode:

- [Dark mode flickers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904)