# How to add an icon inside of a dark mode toggle

Tags: html, css

I want to put an icon inside of the white circle that signifies what the toggle is, but I can't get the icon to show up in the right place, let alone follow where the circle goes. I've been trying to use Font Awesome icons.

### What I want

Either one of these is my end goal, but I still have a hard time figuring out how to make it work.
[image: toggle with icons]

### My Existing Code

If it helps, [this](https://aldriix.neocities.org) is the site I'm working on.

Here is the CSS

```css
/* Toggle Styles */
.toggle-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.toggle input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 34px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2FA28D; /* Color for dark mode background */
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

I don't know if the JavaScript script is important, but here it is:

```js
const modeToggle = document.getElementById('modeToggle');
const body = document.body;

modeToggle.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (modeToggle.checked) {
    body.classList.add('dark-mode');
    body.classList.remove('light-mode');
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark');
  } else {
    body.classList.add('light-mode');
    body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');
  }
});

// Check localStorage for saved mode preference
const savedMode = localStorage.getItem('mode');
if (savedMode === 'dark') {
  body.classList.add('dark-mode');
  modeToggle.checked = true;
} else {
  body.classList.add('light-mode');
  modeToggle.checked = false;
}
```

I've tried placing an `i` element inside the toggle, which looked like this:

```
<label class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="modeToggle">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
  <i class="fas-fa-moon"></i>
</label>
```

vs without it:

```
<label class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="modeToggle">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I've also tried updating the CSS in various other ways that I don't have the remnants of. I'm very new to CSS, so anything will help at this point.

Comment: `<i class="fas-fa-moon"></span>` is invalid. It should be `<i class="fas-fa-moon"></i>`

Comment: @imvain2 my bad! i did do that, i just typed it wrong in the post. let me fix that

Comment: There's no point in removing `light-mode` class just to add `dark-mode` class. If you have only *Dark mode* than you need default styles and just a `.dark-mode`. Not two classes. OK, what if one day you add *fuchsia* mode? Well, in such case you need data attribute `document.documentElement.dataset.mode = "dark"` and in CSS you use: `[data-mode="dark"] #someChild { /* override default CSS vars here*/ }`

Comment: Also, don't use `input:checked` in CSS. If your input is the mode switcher, use it's ID instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You could use some icons or Unicode emoji as child elements, and also CSS-animate them as well.
- Regarding the dark mode toggling the best is to use `data-*` attribute like `data-mode="light"` in the `<html>` element. Then inside JS you can toggle it on the `document.documentElement` (see example)
- To remember the user-desired mode [see this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904)

```js
document.querySelector(".toggle input").addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
  document.documentElement.dataset.mode = evt.currentTarget.checked ? "dark" : "light";
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 0.75rem;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #444;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: translate 0.3s, background-color 0.8s;
  
  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    content: "";
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: translate 0.3s, background-color 0.8s;
    background: #fff;
  }
  
  input {
    position: absolute;
    appearance: none;
  }
  
  span {
    position: relative;
    transition: translate 0.6s ease 0.2s;
    
    &:nth-of-type(1) {
      translate: 0 150%;
    }
    
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      translate: 0 0%;
    }
  }
  
  &:has(input:checked) {
    background-color: #ddd;
    
    span:nth-of-type(1) {
      translate: 0 0%;
    }
    
    span:nth-of-type(2) {
      translate: 0 -150%;
    }
  }
  
  &:has(input:checked)::before {
    translate: 100% 0;
    background-color: #444;
  }
}

/* Use like: */

[data-mode="dark"] {
  body {
    background: #444;
    color: #eee;
  }
  #someSpecificElement {
    /* Some dark mode styles here */
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle" arial-label="Toggle dark mode">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>☀️</span>
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the CSS `content` property and pseudo `::after` element. Necessary comments are added inside the codes.

```css
/* Toggle Styles */
.toggle-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.toggle input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 34px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* added codes */
.slider::after{
  /* You can change the below icon with yours preferable one */
  content: "✹";
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 8px;
  top: 3px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2FA28D; /* Color for dark mode background */
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* added codes */
input:checked + .slider::after{
  transform: translateX(26px);
  content: "☾";
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<label class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="modeToggle">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: What did you mean by "necessary comments"? Comments are by definition not "necessary"?

Comment: By "necessary comments" I mean comments that are required to explain certain codes or adding some important details. Not every single line of codes require a comment.