Get input button to start of container


.dark-light {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    border: #555555 solid;
    background-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    padding: 0.31rem;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    width: 3.8em;
}
.dark-light input {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 2.4rem;
    height: 2.4rem;
    position: absolute;
}
 <li> <div class="dark-light">
                    <input type="button">
                    <span class="light">☀️</span>
                    <span class="dark"></span>
                </div></li>



i wanna get the input to the start of the container div , like to the left, how can i do it
html
<li> <div class="dark-light">
                    <input type="button">
                    <span class="light">☀️</span>
                    <span class="dark"></span>
                </div></li>


css
.dark-light {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    border: #555555 solid;
    background-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    padding: 0.31rem;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
}
.dark-light input {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 2.4rem;
    height: 2.4rem;
    position: absolute;
}

i tried the justify content but it didnt worked , adding left property move it respective to the whole screen because i have absolute position, but i want it the go 100% left of the container

Reminds me of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948817/383904

Your element does not have left/top position, so it's placed with the flow. Add left: 0


.dark-light {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    border: #555555 solid;
    background-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    padding: 0.31rem;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    width: 3.8em;
}
.dark-light input {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 2.4rem;
    height: 2.4rem;
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
}
 <li> <div class="dark-light">
                    <input type="button">
                    <span class="light">☀️</span>
                    <span class="dark"></span>
                </div></li>




yes theres not , because then i taked it to the start of the screen , this toggle im making is part of a bigger navigation bar , adding left 0 takes it to start of screen

you forgot about setting position: relative; to the parent element

thanks adding relative position the parent container worked

@Forgechemist No problem. PS take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948817/383904 for a better implementation. Use rather a checkbox instead of button

It is because of the border and padding. If you remove the border and padding. It looks like:-


.dark-light {
        display: flex;
        gap: 0.75;
        background-color: #555555;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        padding: 0.31rem 0 0.31rem 0;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        align-items: center;
        width: 3.8em;
    }
    .dark-light input {
        border-radius: 2rem;
        appearance: none;
        border: 0;
        width: 2.4rem;
        height: 2.4rem;
        position: absolute;
    }
<li> <div class="dark-light">
        <input type="button">
        <span class="light">☀️</span>
        <span class="dark"></span>
    </div></li>



But, you have to make the height and width 2rem because your border is .4rem.Now, it looks like:-


.dark-light {
        display: flex;
        gap: 0.75;
        background-color: #555555;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        padding: 0.31rem 0 0.31rem 0;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        align-items: center;
        width: 3.8em;
    }
    .dark-light input {
        border-radius: 2rem;
        appearance: none;
        border: 0;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        position: absolute;
    }
<li> <div class="dark-light">
        <input type="button">
        <span class="light">☀️</span>
        <span class="dark"></span>
    </div></li>



Add ul or ol because without ul or ol there is invalid markup, and center the icons also. It will be better.


.dark-light {
        display: flex;
        gap: 0.75;
        background-color: #555555;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        padding: 0.31rem 0 0.31rem 0;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        align-items: center;
        width: 3.8em;
    }
    .dark-light input {
        border-radius: 2rem;
        appearance: none;
        border: 0;
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .center{
        justify-content: center;
    }
 <ul><li> <div class="dark-light">
        <input type="button">
        <span class="center"><span class="light">☀️</span>
        <span class="dark"></span></span>
    </div></li></ul>




<li> without an <ul> or <ol> is invalid markup. Why not add it for completeness? Also your icons are not centered well enough.

Your last example seems a bit odd. The "checkbox" (ahemm) circle is in the center.

It was by mistake. Once more 'Updated the answer.'

Missing position: relative; in .dark-light class.
In .dark-light input you can set position by left: -4px; or right: -4px;


.dark-light {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    border: #555555 solid;
    background-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    padding: 0.31rem;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    align-items: center;
    width: 3.8em;
    position: relative; /* new row */
}
.dark-light input {
    border-radius: 2rem;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    width: 2.4rem;
    height: 2.4rem;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px; /* new variant 1 */
    /* right: -4px; */ /* new variant 2 */
}
    <li> <div class="dark-light">
        <input type="button">
        <span class="light">☀️</span>
        <span class="dark"></span>
    </div></li>




-4px is a magic number.

left: 0; also magic number, why my -4px worse then 0 ?

0 is not considered as a magic number. The use of an arbitrary number like 4 instead necessitates the consideration of documenting this specific choice in-code.

@RokoC.Buljan If you put left:0;, it will be ugly, the easiest way is left:-4px;, I determined this number by testing. I don't like your answer either. Do I have to write comments in CSS? How does left: -4px; differ from gap: 0.75rem;, background-color: #555555;, border-radius: 2rem;, padding: 0.31rem;, width: 3.8em;. ???

Unrelated, but there's also a huge difference between absolute px units and relative scalable units like em rem etc.
