# The button state is not updated on initial rendering

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to integrate a theme button into my website but it doesn't work properly. When the page is refreshed, the button initial phase is retrieving theme from local storage but the button remains with the theme that was set previously.

I want the button to remain locked after setting a statement (light theme or dark one)

Function:

```
// function to set a given theme/color-scheme
function setTheme(themeName) {
  localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
  document.documentElement.className = themeName;
}
// function to toggle between light and dark theme
function toggleTheme() {
 if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark'){
     setTheme('theme-light');
 } else {
     setTheme('theme-dark');
 }
}
// Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
(function () {
 if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
     setTheme('theme-dark');
 } else {
     setTheme('theme-light');
 }
})();
```

CSS:

```
.theme-light {
    --color-body: #2610ff;
    --background-body: #fff;
    --heading-color: #226229;
    --font-color: #000000;
    --color-mainNav: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    --text-mainNav: #333;
    --background-header: #a09b9b42;
    --background-featured: #4b3bf4;
 }
 .theme-dark {
    --color-body: #999CFF;
    --background-body: #000000;
    --heading-color: #3EB14E;
    --font-color: #ffffff;
    --color-mainNav: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    --text-mainNav: #dbd5d5;
    --background-header: #45444880;
    --background-featured: rgb(38, 0, 255);
 }

 /* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
   opacity: 0;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
 }
 
 /* The slider */
 .slider {
   position: relative;
   cursor: pointer;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #ccc;
   -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
   transition: 0.4s;
 }
 .slider:before {
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   left: 0px;
   bottom: 4px;
   top: 0;
   margin: auto 0;
   -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
   transition: 0.4s;
   box-shadow: 0 0px 15px #2020203d;
   background: white url('https://i.ibb.co/7JfqXxB/sunny.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
 }
 
 input:checked + .slider {
   background-color: #2196f3;
 }
 
 input:focus + .slider {
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196f3;
 }
 
 input:checked + .slider:before {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(24px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(24px);
   transform: translateX(24px);
   background: white url('https://i.ibb.co/FxzBYR9/night.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
 }
 /* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
   border-radius: 34px;
 }
 
 .slider.round:before {
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<body class="body">
      <label id="switch" class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleTheme()" id="slider">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  </body>
```

I've created a codepen so maybe someone will help me out with my problem

link: https://codepen.io/cornelius89/pen/xxMZjza

Comment: You could use LocalStorage this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904 and style your button in CSS like: `[data-theme="theme-dark"] #switch { /* override styles here*/  }`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you have forgotten to set initial state for the button when the page loads :

```js
// Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
(function () {
  let crrTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') ?? 'theme-light';
 if (crrTheme === 'theme-dark') {
     setTheme('theme-dark');
 } else {
     setTheme('theme-light');
 }
  document.querySelector("#slider").checked = (crrTheme === 'theme-dark');
})();
```

Additionally, it would we much better to come up with a solution to set state before rendering happens, like putting the function in separate script tag in the `<head>`.

Comment: You should style the button inside the `setTheme` function.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You're right. I tried to provide a simple answer but It can be approved as you mentioned. TNX

Answer (score 0):

On initial load, there should be logic to change the state of the `#slider` checkbox element.

```
// Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
(function () {
  const DEFAULT_THEME = 'theme-light';
  const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || DEFAULT_THEME;
  setTheme(theme);

  // This should set the initial state of the checkbox based on the localStorage data.
  document.getElementById('slider').checked = theme !== DEFAULT_THEME;  
})();
```