# Cannot implement dark and light theme switch

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not able to make the dark and light theme of a website I'm making for class work.

My idea is basically this, as an example I found on a site I use, I want to have the "btn" present in all pages and once I swap the theme it changes for all pages:

[Dark and light theme switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfN0B.gif)

However I can't do it.

this is how my code is at the moment, i don't really know the code sharing is so i apologize if i end up doing a mistake.

My index HTML Page code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- para lingua português é só colocar um pt -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/Costumisation_Index.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../Images/LogoIcon.png">
        <title>HOME</title>
    </head>
    <body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../Images/LogoNavBar.png"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Index.html">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="About.html">ABOUT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Hobbies.html">HOBBIES</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Software.html">SOFTWARE</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="Contacts.html">CONTACTS</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="theme-buttons position-absolute end-0">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light Theme</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark Theme</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
            <div class="split left">
                <div class="centered">
                    <h1>BEM VINDOS</h1>
                    <h3>Ao meu site pessoal</h3>
                    <p>
                        O meu nome é Anibal Artur Pinto Martins Batista da Silva, mas como é muito grande e o meu pai tem um nome parecido ao meu
                        eu simplesmente me introduzo por Anibal Artur Silva.
                    </p>
                    <p>Tenho 30 anos, sou natural da Africa do sul e resido em portugal desde os 4 anos de idade.</p>
                    <p>
                        Desde pequeno que tenho fascinio pela area da multimedia especificamente pela area do Cinema, TV , Imagem e Animação, mas como tenho 0% de talento para o desenho tive
                        que deixar o sonho da animação para traz e focar nas outras duas que é basicamente a area de Imagem e Video.
                    </p>
                    <p>Para saberem mais sobre mim é só seguir as instruções</p>
                    <p><i class="bi bi-arrow-bar-down"></i></p>
                    <a href="About.html" class="btn btn-outline-light botao-pagina">Descobre mais Sobre Mim<i class="bi bi-arrow-right-short"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="split right">
                <div class="centered">
                    <img src="../Images/LogoHome.png" alt="ASilva Personal Logo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="mt-auto text-center text-white">
            <!-- Grid container -->
            <div class="container p-4 pb-0">
            <!-- Section: Social media -->
                <section class="mb-4">
                    <!-- Facebook -->
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1 btn-facebook footer-btn" href="#" role="button"><i class="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>

                    <!-- Twitter -->
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1 btn-twitter footer-btn" href="#" role="button"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>

                    <!-- Discord -->
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1 btn-discord footer-btn" href="#" role="button"><i class="bi bi-discord"></i></a>

                    <!-- Github -->
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1 btn-github footer-btn" href="#" role="button"><i class="bi bi-github"></i></a>
                </section>
            <!-- Section: Social media -->
            </div>
            <!-- Grid container -->

            <!-- Copyright -->
            <div class="text-center p-3 footer-copyright">
            © 2023 Copyright:
            <a class="footer-link" href="#">ASilvaVisualPath.com</a>
            </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
        </footer>
        <script defer src="JavaScript/LightDarkTheme.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-/C2I/9qILMxbZZ0Xr+flJup6UKg2QQ4xMmR02Cq5OfY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Popper.js -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-WW8/jxkELe2CAiE4LvQfwm1rajOS8PHasCCx+knHG0gBHt8EXxS6T6tJRTGuDQVnluuAvMxWF4j8SNFDKceLFg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Index CSS page:

```css
body {
    margin: 0; /* Remove default margin*/
    padding: 0;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Palete de cores*/

/* Light Mode Styles */
body.light-mode {
    background-color: #0080FF;
    color: #1B1B1B;
}

/* Dark Mode Styles */
body.dark-mode {
    background-color: #00437B;
    color: #EDEDED;
}

/* Theme Buttons Styles */

/* Adjust the position of the theme buttons on smaller screens */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .theme-buttons {
        position: static;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
}

/* Adjust the position of theme buttons on larger screens */
@media (min-width: 769px) {
    .position-relative {
        position: relative;
    }
    .position-absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: 150px; /* Adjust the top margin as needed */
        margin-right: 150px;
    }
}

/* Barra de navegação */
.navbar{
    padding: 0;
}

.active{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-link{
    position: relative;
}

.nav-link::after{
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #295773;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.nav-link:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-top-color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom-color: white;
}

.navbar .nav-item{
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.navbar .container-fluid {
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #000033;
    z-index: 1; /* Ensure the navbar is above other elements */
}

.navbar-brand img {
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-height: 100px; /* Adjust the maximum height as needed */
}

.navbar-brand, .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #3FA9F5; /* Text color for the navbar brand and links */
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
    color: #295773;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #fff; /* Border color for the navbar toggle button */
}

/* Divide o ecrã a metade */
.split {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Define layout para coluna */
    justify-content: flex-start; /* Alinhar conteudo ao inicio (topo)*/
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

/*Controlo do lado esquerdo*/
.left {
    padding-left:150px;
    left: 0;
}
    .left h1{
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .left h3{
        font-size: 25px;
    }
    .left p{
        margin-bottom: 15px; /* Adjust the margin-bottom as needed*/
    }

/*Controlo do lado direito*/
.right {
    right: 0;
}

/*Para centralizar o conteudo verticalmente e horizontalmente*/
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
    /*Dar estilo ou formatar a imagem dentro do contentor, se necessario*/
    .centered img {
        width: 500px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

/* Footer styles */
footer {
    background-color: #000033;
    position: relative; /* Important for stacking order */
    
}

.footer-copyright, .footer-link {
    color: #295773; /* Change this to the text color you want in the copyright section */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Facebook icon color */
.btn-facebook {
    color: #3b5998; /* Facebook blue color */
}

/* Twitter icon color */
.btn-twitter {
    color: #1da1f2; /* Twitter blue color */
}

/* Discord icon color */
.btn-discord {
    color: #7289da; /* Discord color */
}

/* Github icon color */
.btn-github {
    color: #4078c0; /* Github color */
}

/* Button outline color */
.footer-btn {
    border-color: #295773; /* Change this to the color you want */
}

/* Button hover effect */
.footer-btn:hover {
    background-color: #295773; /* Change this to the background color you want on hover */
    color: #3FA9F5; /* Change this to the text color you want on hover */
    border-color: #295773; /* Change this to the border color you want on hover */
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```js
// script.js

// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
//     setDefaultTheme();

//     // Add event listeners to theme buttons
//     document.querySelector('.btn-light').addEventListener('click', () => {
//         document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
//         document.body.classList.add('light-mode');
//         localStorage.setItem('preferred-theme', 'light-mode');
//     });

//     document.querySelector('.btn-dark').addEventListener('click', () => {
//         document.body.classList.remove('light-mode');
//         document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
//         localStorage.setItem('preferred-theme', 'dark-mode');
//     });
// });



// LightDarkTheme.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Check if a theme preference is stored
    const preferredTheme = localStorage.getItem('preferred-theme');

    // If a preference is stored, apply it
    if (preferredTheme) {
        document.body.classList.add(preferredTheme);
        toggleThemeButtons();
    } else {
        // If no preference is stored, set the default theme and show only the dark theme button
        setDefaultTheme();
        hideLightThemeButton();
    }

    // Add event listener to the dark theme button
    document.querySelector('.btn-dark').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Toggle between light and dark themes
        document.body.classList.toggle('light-mode');
        document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

        // Toggle the visibility of theme buttons
        toggleThemeButtons();
    });

    // Add event listener to the light theme button
    document.querySelector('.btn-light').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Toggle between light and dark themes
        document.body.classList.toggle('light-mode');
        document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

        // Toggle the visibility of theme buttons
        toggleThemeButtons();
    });

    function setDefaultTheme() {
        document.body.classList.add('light-mode');
    }

    function hideLightThemeButton() {
        document.querySelector('.btn-light').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function toggleThemeButtons() {
        document.querySelector('.btn-light').style.display =
            document.body.classList.contains('light-mode') ? 'none' : 'block';
        document.querySelector('.btn-dark').style.transform =
            document.body.classList.contains('light-mode') ? 'rotateY(0deg)' : 'rotateY(180deg)';
    }
});
```

Comment: Here: [*Switch dark mode theme*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63033934/383904) you have a pretty simple example on how to switch a dark mode theme (without flickering) and properly read the current theme (on another page) from localStorage. To spice things up you could also implement CSS variables (as you can find in the provided question).

Comment: also: `toggleThemeButtons()` is absolutely unnecessary. This can all be done in CSS like i.e: `[data-theme="dark"] #btnMode { /* styles here for button dark theme */ }`

Comment: Also: logic. Makes no sense to have two separate classes `.light-theme, .dark-theme` You just need default styles (you can set in `:root`) and just the overrides for the one you decide, i.e: `[data-theme="dark"] { /*overrides*/ }` and all you need it to toggle that one class (or as I'm pointing to: a `data-*` attribute's value on the HTML or BODY element)

Answer (score 0):

Place this one in `<head>` (before any other tag).
Such will prevent flash of styles (or initial theme toggling animations) because of the render-blocking nature of this script placement:

```html
<script>
// IMPORTANT: set this in <HEAD> top before any other tag.
const setTheme = (theme) => {
  theme ??= localStorage.theme || "light";
  document.documentElement.dataset.theme = theme;
  localStorage.theme = theme;
};
setTheme();
</script>
```

Then, inside your DOM ready script use:

```js
// This script goes right before the closing </body> tag
// or in a DOMContentLoaded function or inside a script with defer attribute
// Add event listener to the theme buttons
document.querySelectorAll("[data-set-theme]").forEach(elBtn => {
  elBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setTheme(elBtn.dataset.setTheme);
  });
});
```

Notice the `data-set-theme` attribute on the theme buttons:

```html
<button type="button" data-set-theme="light">Light Theme</button>
<button type="button" data-set-theme="dark">Dark Theme</button>
```

in CSS define your palette like:

```css
/* Palete de cores */
:root {
  --primary-color: #1B1B1B;
  --bg-primary-color: #0080FF;
  /* Add more theme colors here */
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  --primary-color: #EDEDED;
  --bg-primary-color: #00437B;
  /* Add more theme colors here */
}
```

and use the palette like:

```css
body {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-primary-color);
}
```

And apply per-theme styles like:

```css
#someElement {
  /* "light" (default) theme styles go here */
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
  #someElement {
    /* "dark" theme overrides go here */
  }
}
```

Demo on [jsBin.com](https://jsbin.com/wijemih/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: thanks a lot for the information, i actually after reading your response went to search for a bit some of the stuff you wrote, for example the css part of the root, i had no idea that could be done and my teacher didn't event mention that.

I learned something new.

i am making the changes bit by bit and making improvements still haven't reached the javascript part of it yet tough.

Also i this might be dumb to ask but i need to do these css and html changes in every page i am planing to have right ??

Comment: @ASilva Not sure to understand, but - just make sure that the same CSS file is included in all your different pages. Also, if you are planning to use multiple pages it will be hard to edit stuff in `<head>` navigation, footer for every page... make sure to learn about Templating in a server-side language - or with a frontend build tool (i.e: Handlebars or similar).

Comment: Well i managed to do a switcher theme with some research and help from a tutorial i found on youtube.

it is not entirely what i had in mid, but for a class project i think it works pretty well.

tough for some reason i could not figure out how to place the switcher were i wanted, i must have some css or the html write in a way that prevents me from doing that.

anyway thanks for the help you pointed a lot of stuff that my teach failed to even mention.